# Symfony / Doctrine EntityListener doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I've a problem with an EntityListener... My EntityListener is not called, he doesn't work and I don't know why ! I use Symfony 3.4 and Doctrine 2.5.

So, my Entity :

```php
<?php

namespace TelecomlineBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * LigneTelecom
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="LIGNETELECOM")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="TelecomlineBundle\Repository\LigneTelecomRepository")
 * @ORM\EntityListeners({"TelecomlineBundle\Doctrine\Listener\LigneTelecomListener"})
 */
class LigneTelecom
{
    // etc ...
}
```

My EntityListener :

```php
<?php

namespace TelecomlineBundle\Doctrine\Listener;

use TelecomlineBundle\Entity\LigneTelecom;
use TelecomlineBundle\Service\myService;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class LigneTelecomListener
{
    /** @var myService $myService */
    private $myService;    

    public function __construct(myService $myService)
    {
        $this->myService = $myService;
    }    

    /**
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     *
     * @param LigneTelecom $ligneTelecom
     * @param LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs
     */
    public function postUpdate(LigneTelecom $ligneTelecom, LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $this->myService->calculate($ligneTelecom);
    }  
  
    // etc ...
```

My service.yml :

```yml
telecomline.doctrine.lignetelecom_listener:
    class: "TelecomlineBundle\Entity\LigneTelecom"
    arguments: ["@telecomline.porte"]
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener }
```

If anyone have a solution, I block on that since 3 hours :'(

Comment: 3.4 is getting a bit dated but the 4.4 example should work: https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-entity-listeners

Comment: I know but I work on a big app into a company so the version doesn't depend of my choices

Comment: Nothing wrong with using 3.4.  It is still supported.  I just could not find an example.  Not used to seeing annotation listeners.  Don't really know how that would work.  Remove the annotation.  Update your tagged section and see what happens.

Comment: I've already tried this... 

Without annotations and only with YAML in my service declaration
But same result, the listener doesn't work, he's don't called..

Comment: If you are still having trouble then consider updating your entity file showing the actual annotations used and updating the services.yml file with your tag information.

Comment: You should register the listener class : LigneTelecomListener in the yml file (not your entity)

Comment: Having the same issue, tagged it correctly, but it just never runs

If I use the doctrine annotations it fails because I need dependency injection (and doctrine just instanciate the class by itself)

Comment: So it's apparently super important to tag your service AFTER `App\:` and not even mentioned once in the doc

Answer (score 1):

The Symfony doc is not correct. You don't need a config in services.yaml. Just put an annotation to the entity class like shown on [Doctrine docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.13/reference/events.html#entity-listeners).

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\Entity;
use App\EventListener\UserListener;

#[Entity]
#[EntityListeners([UserListener::class])]
class User
{
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should specify which events subscriber wants to listen to
you use long form of definition or inherit from EventSubscriber and override getSubscribedEvents

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).